# Can the opencv program compiling be independent of Qt in ubuntu14.04?

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu, gcc

In early days, I have installed Qt. Now, I want to write opencv-3.0.0 programs with C language in the terminal of my ubuntu 14.04 in the VM.  I do not want my program have something to do with Qt because later I will package my C language program for the call of java interface on Andriod platform.

In order that my program is not affected by the Qt library function, I shielded the path variables of Qt in the /etc/bash.bashrc file. But it does not work. I cannot understand the compiling error. Why the compiler always finds gcc in Qt5? Of course,the path in error "/home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc" is s where I installed my Qt5, but I have installed a new gcc successfully.

A simple example is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
  Mat img = imread("cornea.jpg");
  imshow("src, img");
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it with gcc-5.3.0 by using this command:

> g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs opencv`

the compiling result is as follows:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /usr/bin/ld: warning: libicudata.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_clone_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘uenum_next_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_strToLower_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getStandardName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_setAttribute_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_setMillis_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_strcoll_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_setSubstChars_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getTimeZoneDisplayName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openCountryTimeZones_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_fromUnicode_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_open_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getDefaultName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_open_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_close_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_inDaylightTime_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_getSortKey_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getAvailableName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_close_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_get_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openTimeZoneIDEnumeration_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getDSTSavings_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_open_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openTimeZones_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_toUnicode_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_strToUpper_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_errorName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_close_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘uenum_close_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_countAvailable_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getMaxCharSize_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getAlias_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getDefaultTimeZone_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_compareNames_54’未定义的引用
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Using the command line:

> which gcc

the answer is:

> /usr/gcc-5.0.0/bin/gcc

So strange!

Here I want to ask a question: can the opencv program compiling be independent of Qt?  Could you help?

Comment: Those are all linker errors, and it looks like you're linking with Qt libraries.

Comment: You can compile the same opencv code in g++, via the terminal on your Ubuntu. Enter the following on your terminal:  g++ main.cpp -o outp -L/usr/include -L/usr/include/opencv -L/opencv/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.3/include  -L/usr/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video

Comment: Now I will put the source code on this page. I edit my question now!

Comment: I have put my source code on this page. I wonder: why do the opencv program of showing pictures will have a relationship with Qt5? Linking Qt libraries is not my intention.I do not want my program have something to do with Qt because later I will package my C language program for the call of java interface on Andriod platform.

Comment: We don't need your source code, we need your project file (make file, qmake file?). I suppose you use QtCreator as IDE?

Comment: my friend, My intention are writing opencv-3.0.0 programs with C language in the terminal of my ubuntu 14.04 in the VM and just compiling them with gcc. I do not want my programs have something to do with Qt. Is it realizable?

Comment: Yes, it is relizable. But can you provide your project files? How do you compile your program?

Comment: You can use C++ for your program. You can use C only for define JNI functions.

Comment: I've got your meaning. In fact, I am a green hand, now let me explain my idea in detail. I have not created the project file. I am just doing a test by the .cpp file of showing pictures. I compile it by g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs opencv`. But the error above always exists! How could I have the makefile？

Comment: I'm not an ubuntu user, so I can't help you much. You can see this question http://answers.opencv.org/question/25642/how-to-compile-basic-opencv-program-in-c-in-ubuntu

Comment: also failed, I do not know where the problem is. So depressed!